# Monitor screen vertically split in half

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display

I have a huge bug on my screen, it is vertically split in two:

[image: picture]

I did nothing "wrong" with my computer. The only thing a recently did is playing Skyrim Special Edition with like 30 mods.

My configuration:

- OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1
- GPU : Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB (bought 5 months ago)
- Monitor: an Iiyama that is plugged in DVI (supporting D-Sub and HDMO too)

I have read a lot of things on the Internet but no one has the same problem as me, what can I do/try?

Comment: If you look at the bottom it seems to be more than just the split in the middle. Did you try to reboot? What did you do before you noticed it? Is something from the top of the screen missing as well? As the Windows button is in the middle, does it wrap around? Do you have that error during boot? Did you try to boot into safe mode and does the error exist there as well?

Comment: I try to reboot yes and it didn't change anything. Unfortunately the bug starts at the very begining of the boot : http://imgur.com/a/FL4wY . So even in safe mode it's the same. Also, the top of the screen is indeed missing and the bottom have "something more". Moreover, the left side of the screen is fuzzy while the right one is fine.
Edit : I will try with another monitor tomorrow...

Comment: Hardware issue or too high frame rate: Your screen is not spilt into half, it is shifted by half width and wrapped around. Could be a sync problem, maybe caused by too high frame rate. Also check cables.